# Salesforce for Outlook is not showing in salesforce

Tags: outlook, salesforce

I'm working on connecting salesforce with outlook to share salesforce events with outlook. but there is no "Salesforce for Outlook" link. does any one know how to find it?

Comment: (1) Check with Salesforce support (2) Check salesforce for Outlook is available in Office store, download, install/configure and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are looking for, you can use this URL:

- YOURSALESFORCEDOMAIN/lightning/setup/EmailConfigurations/home

or this one:

- YOURSALESFORCEDOMAIN/lightning/setup/LightningForOutlookAndSyncSettings/home

For further details, you may check out these help articles:

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lightning_sync_admin_overview.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.email_int_overview.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Go to outlook -> Add ins -> search for Salesforce for Outlook in the store -> and install it. Once you install it you will find a salesforce cloud icon in the outlook tool ribbon beside the phishing symbol. Click on the icon and integrate it with your instance, username and password. Once successfully logged in check in the Outlook Integration & sync in Setup of salesforce.